# Heroku no reconoce mi variable de entorno

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

bueno mi problema es el que se describe en el titulo.
Estoy haciendo el despliegue de una app de node.js en heroku, la dirección de la DB esta guardada en un archivo .env (dependencia dotenv).

Al hacer el deploy en heroku, la app funciona, a excepción de las funciones con la DB ya que la app no reconoce la variable de entorno con los datos en archivo .env que configuro en heroku.

Como podría hacer que funcione la variable previamente mencionada?

Aclaro que de manera local la app funciona sin problemas.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Player = require('./models/player') 
const app = express()

dotenv.config()
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que Heroku identifique variables de entorno, estas deben estar configuradas directamente en el dashboard de Heroku.

Hace tiempo que no lo uso, pero recuerdo que en los ajustes del proyecto hay un apartado donde puedes definirlas.

Algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ver más en: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Si, es exactamente como esta configurada en mi proyecto, pero no funciona, hay algo que deba agregar en mi código para que sea reconocido?

Comment: No, se supone que eso es todo para hacerlas funcionar. Prueba reiniciando el Dyno y verificar que no haya un error de escritura en la variable

Comment: Estoy teniendo el siguiente error, supongo que tendré que configurarlo desde mongo atlas: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: Exactamente, lo que sucede es que tienes el acceso a tu cluster para una serie de IPs (Por ejemplo, la de tu maquina de desarrollo). Lo que debes hacer es contratar un private space de Heroku para obtener la IP de tu Dyno y agregarla a tu lista de IPs permitidas en el cluster de Mongo, o en su defecto, modificar la seguridad de tu cluster para que cualquier IP tenga accesso (algo que no se recomienda).

Comment: Puedes saber más de ello en este link: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/connect-atlas-to-heroku-hosted-app/7202

Comment: solucionado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Me paso algo similar, la momento de hacer un deploy.
Tiene que reviar si el directorio en donde estan las variables de entorno estan en el gitignore.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340252)